# calling member function without object error: C++ / (G++) oop

Tags: c++, oop

i was curious to know why the following throws an error in g++ (cannot call member function without object). I suppose a workaround would be to have the B class variable as static variable in A - but i was curious to find out why, when there is an instance of A's child class C created, this still throws an error - many thanks!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;


class B {
public:
  double var;

public:
  friend class A; 
  B() : var(1) { };
  void set(double new_rate);
};


class A {
protected:
   B main_B;

public:
  virtual void set_rate(double new_rate) { cout << "test"; 
   //B.set(new_rate); 
  }

};



class C : public A {

};

/*
void B::set(double new_rate) {
  var = new_rate;
  cout << "worked " <<current_rate <<endl;
}

*/



int main() {

  C test_C;
  A::set_rate ( 2.00 );
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Firstly,

```
C test_c();
```

does not create an instance of C, it declares a function that returns a C. You mean:

```
C test_c;
```

Secondly, non-static member functions can only be called on a specific instance of a class. So with the corrected code, you could say:

```
test_c.set_rate( 2.0);
```

Comment: C test_c(); is as valid as C test_c; both create a variable. () means that the ctor has no parmaters. -1 until proven otherwise.

Comment: thanks, corrected the instanciation.

so methods cant be call the parent class (say, if its pure virtual) only on a specific instance (of a child class)?

Comment: @the_drow  I don't need to prove anything - you need to read book on C++.

Comment: the_drow i think you are correct, it woudl use the default constructor, but was irrelevant in this case so made the code simpler..

Comment: @the_drow: `C test_c();` is a function declaration, not an object declaration (and definition). I suggest you remove your -1; Neil is right.

Comment: Just checked it, and he is correct. No idea why though.
I tried to remove the downvote but it can't be removed unless the question is edited.

Comment: The reason why is that both C and C++ have the rule that anything that can be parsed as a declaration will be so parsed. This looks like a function declaration, so that's what the parser thinks it is.

Comment: @the_drow:Google for "most vexing parse" and you should find quite a bit about this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an explicit `<class>::` to call a non-static member function, thereby disabling any virtual function mechanism, but for a non-static member you still need to specify a class instance on which to call the function.

e.g.

```
int main()
{
    C test_C;
    test_C.A::set_rate(2.00);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why the use of the A:: scope specification?

Comment: I don't think that there is a good reason in this instance - tbh, I wasn't really sure exactly what the OP needed - but looking at the commented out code it might be something that OP is experimenting with.

Comment: had seen something similar, and was pretty sure it was done without satic, so trying to figure out how!